# How can I have nginx in one container and php-fpm in another?

Tags: php, nginx, docker

I am trying to create two docker containers. One would contain nginx, and another would contain php-fpm. Here is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '2'
services:
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
  fpm:
    build: ./php
    volumes:
      - ./php/code:/var/www/html/
```

### NGINX

Here is my `Dockerfile` for the `nginx` container:

> FROM nginx:latest RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf COPY
>   ./default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/

And, here is my `default.conf`:

```
server {
    listen  80;

    server_name localhost;
    root /var/www/html;

    error_log /var/log/nginx/localhost.error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/localhost.access.log;

    location / {
        # try to serve file directly, fallback to app.php
        try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ ^/.+\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass fpm:9000;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS off;
    }
}
```

This is all my nginx configuration.

### PHP

Here is the `Dockerfile` in the `./php` directory:

```
from php:fpm
COPY ./code/ /var/www/html/
```

Inside the `./code` directory, i have a file named `app.php` that contains `phpinfo()`.

### The Problem

I run `docker-compose up` and when I try to open `192.168.99.100` (the IP of the docker machine in which docker engine is running), I get `File not found`. I have also tried `192.168.99.100/app.php`, but it's the same.

What am I configuring wrong? I saw in an example on the Internet that the PHP files must live in the `nginx` container, but that doesn't make any sense since as far as I know, `php-fpm` is the process that must have access to those files.

Answer (score 3):

The reason for your 404 error is that your Nginx container has no files in it.

You must link the same files you linked into the PHP-FPM container into the Nginx container:

```
version: '2'
services:
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./php/code:/var/www/html/

  fpm:
    build: ./php
    volumes:
      - ./php/code:/var/www/html/
```

When the request reaches the web-server, the file must at least exist before the Nginx can pass the request along to the PHP-FPM container. You could even make the folder read-only for the Nginx container:

```
version: '2'
services:
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./php/code:/var/www/html/:ro

  fpm:
    build: ./php
    volumes:
      - ./php/code:/var/www/html/
```

Comment: Ah. So there's no way to not have the files in the nginx container? I'm asking because in my nginx Dockerfile I will have to copy the files into the image anyway (for production use) and I'm wondering if there's a way to not increase the image size. Or, is it just wiser to put the whole thing in one container? I am trying to follow the Docker best practices which says that: "In almost all cases, you should only run a single process in a single container. Decoupling applications into multiple containers makes it much easier to scale horizontally and reuse containers."

Comment: From my experience I would use volumes and link the files into the containers and never put two applications into the same container.

In my mind the container is the execution unit for the application code and I would not compile a docker image that contains the code and the application.

If you still want to put your application code into a docker image, I would build one docker image which contains only the application code and use that as the source for Nginx and PHP.

Comment: Thanks! I updated my `docker-compose.yml` file and added the new volume. However, I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Sorry. The reason it wasn't working was because i needed to force the image to be built by typing `docker-compose build`.

Answer (score 0):

After doing what has been suggested in the other answer and spending about six hours or more on this issue, I found that the reason my set up wasn't working was because `docker-compose up` does not rebuild your images, so the configuration in the container was an older version.

So, fixing this was as easy as `docker-compose build` and then `docker-compose up`.

Sorry for taking everyone's time.

Comment: `docker-compose up --build` will rebuild your images before starting the containers.